# Symfony 3 - can't use custom Repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

I try to create default repository in my Symfony 3. First I created Repository class with method 'findByParentOrderedByName'. In next step I added in Entity line:

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ChildRepository")
```

Unfortunelly when I try to run findByParentOrderedByName() I get error

> Undefined method 'findAllOrderedByName'. The method name must start with either findBy, findOneBy or countBy!

What I make incorrect?

Repository code:

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    /**
     * Child
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ChildRepository")
     */
    class Child
    {
    ........
    }
```

Comment: findByParentOrderedByName findAllOrderedByName hmmm

Comment: Can you post your repository code?

Comment: I added repository code

Comment: Show us your ChildRepository class

Answer (score 1):

To use custom repository class properly, firstly repository class name must be defined in entity class.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ChildRepository")
 */
class Child
{
}
```

Then repository class created as like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ChildRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return Child[]
     */
    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT * c FROM AppBundle:Child c ORDERED BY c.name ASC')
            ->getResult();

    }
}
```